# Downsize a List<xyz> with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'd like pick out a List the items 5 - 10 and create a new list of the same type.
Using Linq I thought of:

```
List<xyz> collection = new <List>();
//fill collection with lots of data
collection.AddRange( ... );

//Downsize here
var q = from e in collection select e;
q.ToArray();
List<xyz> smallcollection = new List<xyz>()
smallcollection = q.Skip(5).Take(5);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well first of all, what happens? How is the result wrong?

Comment: 5-10 is 6 items; do you mean Take(6)? or 5-9?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just `var newList = q.Skip(5).Take(5).ToList()`...  your existing code is creating a lot of objects but not using them; the "`ToArray()`" is discarded, as is the "`new List<xyz>()`". There's also a "`collection.Select(e=>e)`" that does not a lot... (hidden in LINQ query syntax).

Answer (score 2):

Last line should be

```
smallcollection = q.Skip(5).Take(5).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If the original list is a `List<T>`, you don't need LINQ at all.

You can use the [`GetRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c.aspx) method, like this:

```
List<xyz> collection = new <List>();
//fill collection with lots of data
collection.AddRange( ... );


List<xyz> smallCollection = collection.GetRange(5, 5);
```

---

If it isn't a `List<T>`, you can use LINQ like this:

```
List<xyz> smallCollection = q.Skip(5).Take(5).ToList();
```